# WPF get every 'secondary child nodes' in a master node

Tags: c#, xml

I have the current xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Master>
    <Child1>
        <Display>Some things here</Display>
        <Link>http://google.ca</Link>
        <Description>Desc</Description>
        <Image>http://google.ca</Image>
    </Child2>
</Master>
```

I already figured out how to get the link using `doc.SelectSingleNode("Master/Child1/Link").InnerText;`

But now, I need a way to list every child (Like Child1, there is way more than that which all have subnodes like link, display....)

I tried a bunch of things but all I found online was how to get "name" from `<Master name="Name Here"/>`

Also, I'd need it to act as a String (being able to print it to console without getting `System.xml.XmlNode`)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use JSON.NET, this is not a WPF question per se.

Comment: Use xml linq doc.Root.Elements().ToList().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xpath `*` matches any node.

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("Master/*/Link");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

---

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("Master/*");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I know how to access a single node I need to get an array/list containing every child nodes but not subchild... Example: list would return `["Child1"], ["Child2"], ["Child3"]` Without having the `<Link>, <Description>, <Display>, <Image>` in it... Your method also displays theses.